# How to find Docker container's layer ID and reuse it in another container

Tags: docker, containers, layer

I found layers and diffs in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/`, but as I understood from Docker documentation layer ID not matching container IDs and docker inspect not showing layers either.

I'm wondering if I can reuse docker image layers in another container without creating new image, is there way to do that? Is there way to find layers IDs for container?

**UPDATE**

I made 2 containers from one base image - ubuntu:trusty. Then in one container I updated repositories and installed vim (adds ~65mb). Then I copied files from diff of one container to another. Started vim and it worked.

But main question remains - **how to get layers IDs of container?**

**UPDATE2**

Found all I need in `/var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb/mounts/<CONTAINER_ID>/mount-id`

Comment: Even if there is a way to use them, I don't think it's safe. They are implementation details, after all. And the implementation can change anytime, without notice.

Comment: Please see my edited question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. In this [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#use-a-dockerignore-file) it states:

> Starting with a base image that is already in the cache, the next
>   instruction is compared against all child images derived from that
>   base image to see if one of them was built using the exact same
>   instruction. If not, the cache is invalidated.

Comment: Isn't that case for building images? Can I just create new container using base image, and then there, as documentation says, will be created new container layer where all my changes will be. So if I could find out what ID is this container's layer has, could I just copy changes from one container's layer to new one?

Comment: I am not sure if you could do this. But one way to do it I believe is just to make a docker image for the things you need (common base). Then after that you could `FROM <the image you just built>` in your Dockerfile.